# Custom Label Angular Formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I want to customize label in angular formly.

I know that you can set `label` attribute in `templateOptions` object like this:

```
type: 'input',
key: 'firstName',
templateOptions: {
    type: 'text',
    label: 'Name',
    required: true
}
```

but I need to insert HTML in label, something like this (example with bootstrap tooltip):

```
type: 'input',
key: 'firstName',
templateOptions: {
    type: 'text',
    label: 'Name <i tooltip title="Insert your First Name">?</i>',
    required: true
}
```

I've also searched in documentation but I didn't find anything that helped me or that was well explained.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a bit late, but I had the same need, and this is how I managed it after some searching:

```js
/* global angular */
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('formlyExample', ['formly', 'formlyBootstrap', 'ngSanitize'], function config(formlyConfigProvider) {
    // set templates here
    formlyConfigProvider.setType({
      name: 'inputLabelHtml',
      extends: 'input',
      templateUrl: 'input-label.html',
      wrapper: ['bootstrapHasError']
    });

  });


  app.controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl(formlyVersion) {
    var vm = this;


    vm.fields = [

      {
        key: 'awesomeName',
        type: 'inputLabelHtml',
        templateOptions: {
          label: 'Name <i tooltip title="Insert your First Name">?</i>'
        }
      }

    ];

  });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Twitter bootstrap -->
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- apiCheck is used by formly to validate its api -->
  <script src="//npmcdn.com/api-check@latest/dist/api-check.js"></script>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.4.7/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

  <!-- This is the current state of master for formly core. -->
  <script src="//npmcdn.com/angular-formly@latest/dist/formly.js"></script>
  <!-- This is the current state of master for the bootstrap templates -->
  <script src="//npmcdn.com/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap@latest/dist/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap.js"></script>

  <title>Angular Formly HTML in Label example</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="formlyExample" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <div>

    <form ng-submit="vm.onSubmit()" name="vm.form" novalidate>
      <formly-form model="vm.model" fields="vm.fields" options="vm.options" form="vm.form">

      </formly-form>
    </form>

  </div>


  <!--custom templates -->

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="input-label.html">
    <div class="text">
      <label>
           <div  ng-bind-html="to.label"> </div>
            </label>
      <input type="input" class="formly-field-input" ng-model="model[options.key]"> {{to.required ? '*' : ''}}

    </div>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```